# uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined backbone.js

Tags: javascript, html, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I 'm trying to develop a simple RSS app using backbone.js. I 'm using this backbone.js [tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-2-crud/). I 'm getting the following error, on line 2(template), when defining the template. 
Can someone also tell me why is tagName: "li" defined in the tutorial?

> uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
>   backbone.js

**Javscript**

```
window.SourceListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:"li",
    template: _.template($('#tmpl_sourcelist').html()),

    initialize:function () {
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
        this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    },

    render:function (eventName) {
        $(this.$el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    close:function () {
        $(this.el).unbind();
        $(this.el).remove();
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <script type="text/template" id="tmpl_sourcelist">
                        <div id="source">
                        <a href='#Source/<%=id%>'<%=name%></a>
                        </div>
                </script>
```

thanks

Comment: try running the template without the data and see what you get...this.$el.html(this.template())

Comment: It errors out at line2(template: _.template($('#tmpl_sourcelist').html()),). Not sure what are you recommending.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You're getting your error right here:

```
template: _.template($('#tmpl_sourcelist').html()),
```

Part of `_.template`'s internals involves calling [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on the uncompiled template text on the way to producing the compiled template function. That particular error usually means that you're effectively saying this:

```
_.template(undefined)
```

That can happen if there is no `#tmpl_sourcelist` in the DOM when you say `$('#tmpl_sourcelist').html()`.

There are a few simple solutions:

1. Adjust your `<script>` order so that your `#tmpl_sourcelist` comes before you try to load your view.
2. Create the compiled template function in your view's `initialize` instead of in the view's "class" definition:

   ```
   window.SourceListView = Backbone.View.extend({
       tagName:"li",
       initialize:function () {
           this.template = _.template($('#tmpl_sourcelist').html());
           //...
   ```

As far as `tagName` goes, the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) has this to say:

> **el** `view.el`
>
> [...] `this.el` is created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id` and `attributes` properties, if specified. If not, **el** is an empty `div`.

So having this in your view:

```
tagName: 'li'
```

means that Backbone will automatically create a new `<li>` element as your view's `el`.

Comment: great answer! It helped me out in my situation because  $("#target").html(_.template(template, [posts]));  was looking for an id = target but it was a class.

Comment: @Anthony: Thanks. So the same `_.template(undefined)` problem in disguise then.