# Uncaught Error: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined - Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I constantly keep getting this error.
Here is my code:

Template

```
<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
<div>
  <input id="todo_complete" type="checkbox" <%= completed ? 'checked="checked"' : '' %>>
  <%= title %>
</div>
</script>
```

View

```
    var dashBoardView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(),
    model: item1,
    render: function(){
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
      return this;
    }
  });
  var dbView = new dashBoardView({
     el: $("#item-template")
  });
```

How should I get rid of my error?Can anyone tell me the right way to render this view?

Comment: What's the call stack?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined underscore.js:1235
_.template underscore.js:1235
init                  Does this help?or you need more code from the js file?

Comment: there are too many errors in your code to enumerate. take a look at some basic Backbone tutorials.

Comment: Oh! Can you atleast tell me a couple?I think it has got to be something with the way I have declared the template variable in the view. But I am not sure.

Comment: Check out [uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined backbone.js](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14826412/722238).