# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined _.template underscore.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I have edited this question because people are pointing me to this link:-
 
[uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826149/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-replace-of-undefined-backbone-js)

But I think these two questions are different, also the solution provided there is already implemented here. People also mentioned that the code is working on their end, if you are executing this code on your machine then please click on the `Home Page` link and let me know if the Home Page view is loading in your end.

**Actual Question** 
I am new to Backbone.js and currently going through the tutorials. I see that different developers use different ways to accomplish a task, so I tried to mix match their approaches to understand it in more depth and have a clear concept. What I am trying to achieve here in my code is to perform switch view using a Router, and this is how my code looks (I have trimmed it down to the basics so that it easy to debug) -

```
        <script type="text/template" id="home-template">
            <h1>This is the home page</h1>
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
                tagName: 'div',
                initialize: function() {
                    $("body").html(this.el);
                    this.template = _.template($('#home-template').html());
                    this.render();
                },
                render: function() {
                    this.$el.html(this.template());
                }
            });

            var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
                routes: {
                    'home': 'home'
                },
                home: function() {
                    this.view = new HomeView();
                }
            });

            var appRouter = new AppRouter();
            Backbone.history.start();
        </script>

        <a href = "#/home">Home Page</a> <br />
```

So when I am loading the page it is loading correctly, but when I am clicking on the `Home Page` link, it is getting a JS error in the line -

`this.template = _.template($('#home-template').html());`

I have also added a screenshot of the problem that I am facing. I went through the solutions given in *stackoverflow* for this kind of error and also modified my code according to the changes suggested, but it didn't work. The issue is, the `_.template` function is not able to identify the `home-template` template. Any idea why is it so and how to resolve it?

Comment: One more thing when I am replacing the line `this.template = _.template($('#home-template').html());` with `this.template = _.template("<h1>This is the home page</h1>");` it is working as expected. So I am pretty sure the error I am facing is because `home-template` is invisible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826149/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-replace-of-undefined-backbone-js)

Comment: @Louis if you see the two solutions provided in the answer, I have applied both. I have adjusted my `<script>` order for the template and also `created the compiled template function in the initialize`. Do you see anything I am missing out here? If yes, please point out.

Comment: What exactly do you see when you click on the link `Home Page`? Is the home page view loading where there is the header present?

Comment: @Louis you didn't get the error because I trimmed down the code and put only the erroneous part. I have modified my code and added the other bit where it is trying to render the `Home View`. Try now and see if you are getting the error or not. Also to replicate the error, as mentioned above you have to click on the `Home Page` link.

Answer (score 4):

`$("body").html(this.el);` does not do whatever you thought it does. You must remove that.

What this does is replace the HTML of the element named `body` with the value of `this.el`. When you replace the contents of `body`, you also erase all your `script` elements and thus `$('#home-template').html()` fails to find an element with id `home-template` and returns the result `undefined` which causes a failure later when you try to use your template.

In order to give a element to which your view will be attached, you can create an element for it in the HTML:

```
<div id="view">
</div>
```

And pass it to your view when you create it, or pass a CSS selector:

```
this.view = new HomeView({ el: "#view" });
```

Comment: You were right about `$("body").html(this.el);`, it was replacing all the `script` elements. But if I remove this line, the `Home View` is not rendering only, I don't know why. So what I did is, I put that line after this line `this.template = _.template($('#home-template').html());`. This way it was able to find the `home-template` script. And now it is working as expected.